# Make a RTP-MIDI session in "Midi Network Setup" reconnect to a participant after reboot

Tags: command-line, bash, automation, midi

In a studio setup, I need an RTP-Midi (AppleMidi) session, that is set up via "Audio MIDI Setup" to reinitiate with a participant, after reboot. At the moment, the Session is active but the Mac doesn't automatically send an invitation to the participant. It is set up manually in the "Directory" list, not via Bonjour.

Can I trigger this via the command line? Then I would be happy to write a bash script to do that.

This is how the Session looks initiated:

[image: Set-up and connected RTP-Midi Session]

After reboot:

[image: Set-up but not connected RTP-Midi Session]

Comment: did you end up finding a solution to this?! I’m trying to do the same thing, closest I have come is to use a keystroke recorder and playback specific mouse and keyboard movements but the directory list of devices changes order so it’s not consistent. Love to hear if you get something working